# Javascript random generation

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to make the td and tr do a random number of columns and and rows when the window is refreshed. I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the math here. I haven't use this function before so I know something is not right.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmousedown='event.preventDefault();'>
 <head>
 <title> Boxes </title>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <style>

table {
   border-spacing: 6px;
   border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
   margin-top: .5in;
   margin-left: 1in;
 }




   td {
  width: 40px; height: 40px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  }



 </style>
 <script>
```

This function returns a random value between min and max inclusive.

```
  function R(min, max) {
   var range = Math.abs(max-min)+1;
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*range) + min);
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
  <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td> 
 <tr>
  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td> 
 <tr>
  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td> 
  <tr>
  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td> 
  <script>
```

Use document.write() and for-loops to make a rows x cols table of empty
cells styled according to the rules in the style section.  rows and cols
should be set to a random number between 4 and 16.  Each time the page is
re-loaded the table should likely be a different size.

```
 for(r=4; r<16; r++){
  var row ="td";
 for(c=4; c<16;c++){
  row+="tr";
  }console.log(row);
  }


 </script>
 </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Where are you using document.write()?

Comment: I failed to. I should have where console.log(row); was essentially but even then my code isn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in example, i have added the script directly within body to append the required HTML to keep it simple

**About your code :**
well,in your posted snippet you were using console.log() which is used for writing the output to console not on your web page in order to do so you have to add it to Document object (your page) a simple method is to use

```
document.write('markup here');
```

follow [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) to know about the write method.

about how rows and cols generated ie. `Math.random() * (max - min) + min` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/6869708) is some best explanation

```css
table {
      border-spacing: 6px;
      border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
    }

td {
    width: 20px; height: 40px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Lets first Set Min and max here you want min to 4 and max to 16 so we declare here.
      var min = 4, max =16;
      var row = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      var cols = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      //lets print someoutput
      for(var i=0;i<row;i++)
      {
        document.write("</tr>"); // we are printing HTML so use tags <tr> not tr
        for(var j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
          document.write("<td>dummy</td>"); // we are printing HTML so use tags <td> not td
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
      }
  </script>
</table>
```

Comment: Are your double colons deliberate? And how does this code work, what benefits does it offer over the OP's original code? What was wrong with that original code?

Comment: @DavidThomas did you wait for answerer to update....nd double colons were typos and i guess the update should help the OP.. still anything left please point dont just downvote...

Comment: This is a great example!!! This is how I think it should look! I really appreciate the comments. As I said above I have been spending time offline trying to get this to work. The document.write was my missing puzzle piece.

Comment: @RohitS I don't understand what the for loop variables actually do here for(var i=0;i<row;i++) same goes for j.

Comment: @LarryG glad it helped you.. :D now,moving to your question, the loops are for printing the output. first we calculate the rows and columns required with `Math.random() * (max - min) + min;` now have to print the output for number of rows and for each rows the number of columns so outer loop decides number of rows and for each row (i.e i) we have inner loop of j which prints columns.. i hope that make sense to you

Comment: Definitely does help me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

> Table with dynamic rows and columns

[Working Example](http://codepen.io/SoEzPz/pen/KWjmbb) CodePen

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

var randomNum = (function(min, max){
  return function(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (Math.abs(max-min)+1)) + min);
  }
}(4,16))

document.write(createTable(randomNum(), randomNum()));

function createTable(rowCt, colCt){
  var table = "<table>";
  for(var index = 0; index < rowCt; index++){
    table += createRow(colCt);
  }
  return (table + "</table>");
}

function createRow(num){
  return ("<tr>" + createColumns(num) + "</tr>")
}

function createColumns(num){
  var columns = "";
  for(var index = 0; index < num; index++){
    columns += "<td></td>";
  }
  return columns;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 6px;
  border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
  margin-top: .5in;
  margin-left: 1in;
}

td {
  width: 40px; height: 40px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: I have been working on this myself and like you guys pointed out I went wrong with not using the document.write() it seems that it is impossible to find an example that uses the document.write for more than just simple text writing. I didn't know the write could be used like this. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `R()` function is generating a random number between the passed params. What you were doing is that you were not using that random number to print out the random number of rows / cols.

I've created a function called `generateRandomSizedTable`, and wrapped your snippet, with corrections, to print out random set of rows and columns and wrap it with a wrapper block called `table_wrapper` on `document.onload`.

```js
function R(min, max) {
   var range = Math.abs(max-min)+1;
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*range) + min);
}

function generateRandomSizedTable(){
  var table = "<table>";
  var rows = R(4, 16);
  var cols = R(4, 16);
  for(r=1; r <= rows; r++){
      table += "<tr>";
      for(c=1; c <= cols;c++){
          table+="<td></td>";
      }
      table += "</tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("table_wrapper").innerHTML = table;
  console.log(table);
}

document.onload = generateRandomSizedTable();
```

```css
table {
   border-spacing: 6px;
   border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
   margin-top: .5in;
   margin-left: 1in;
}
td {
   width: 40px; height: 40px; 
   border: 1px solid black;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: And how does your code work? What benefits does it offer? What was the problem with the OP's code, where did it go wrong? Why should he "*try this*"?

Comment: actually i forgot to add comments with my answer due to slow connection and opening up the snippet insertor after lot of efforts. i'll put my points in a minute

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for pointing out the mistake. You may improve the answer now if you find it lacking somewhere.